# Setting assembly icons on-the-fly in Wix at build or install time

Tags: c#, .net, wix

In my Wix project, I have multiple cultures configured. One of the cultures requires unique icons for two of the assemblies (the main executable and one of the DLLs).

I am a Wix novice, first of all. I have two ideas for how to approach this. In both cases, I will use Einar Egilsson's InsertIcons tool, described in his blog post [here](http://einaregilsson.com/add-multiple-icons-to-a-dotnet-application/). In Visual Studio, I would configure these assemblies' project files to specify the default icon. That is, no icon.

The first idea, then, is to use InsertIcons to set the assemblies' icon during the Wix build time. So, before the assemblies are processed, I'd execute InsertIcons.exe, specifying the appropriate icon for the culture that is being built. Even though only one culture needs the unique icons, I'd have to set the icons for each assembly always, because the assemblies would be built without an icon. Problems with this approach: I am not sure how to launch a standalone executable during the Wix build process, or even if it can be done.

The second idea is to do the job at install time using a custom action. My understanding is that I could wrap up InsertIcons.exe, along with the necessary .ICO files as a binary that goes into the MSI. Then, after the assemblies have been copied to the target folder, my custom action would launch InsertIcons to set the assemblies' icons. Problems with this approach: I think I'd have to copy InsertIcons and the .ICO files out of the MSI and into a temp folder first. Also, I think that if I modify the assemblies in this way, they won't be properly deleted in an uninstall scenario.

Am I on the right track with either of these ideas, or is there a better way to do the job? It seems you can do just about anything in Wix, but the only problem is finding out how to actually do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use the post-build event to make a copy of the assemblies into a culture folder (bin\Release\xx-XX). Then, InsertIcons is used to set the culture-specific icons of these copies. In order for InsertIcons to set the 0th icon in the assembly (which it will not do if there is already a 0th icon), the assembly projects were changed to specify the default icon (that is, no icon).

Then, in Wix, when building the culture in question, the assemblies are pulled from the culture folder (bin\Release\xx-XX), instead of the usual source folder (bin\Release).